# How to keep current line centered vertically on the screen in Sublime Text?

Tags: plugins, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I want to keep the currently selected line at the vertical center of the screen.

In VIM this is achieved with the `:set scrolloff=9999` command.

Is there any option or plugin to do that in Sublime Text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import sublime_plugin
class AlwaysCenterCommand(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_modified(self, view):
        sel = view.sel()
        pt = sel[0].begin() if len(sel) == 1 else None
        if pt != None:
            view.show_at_center(pt)
```

Center if not multi selection and modifying. That is it.

Or alternatively you could just use the region.

```
import sublime_plugin
class AlwaysCenterCommand(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_modified(self, view):
        sel = view.sel()
        region = sel[0] if len(sel) == 1 else None
        if region != None:
            view.show_at_center(region)
```

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/always-centered-cursor/4005

---

**Another Option**

> Buffer Scroll is a simple Sublime Text plug-in which remembers and restores the scroll, cursor positions, also the selections, marks, bookmarks, foldings, selected syntax and optionally the colour scheme, when you open a file. Will also remember different data depending the position of the file in the application (example file1 in window1 has scroll line 30, file1 in window2 has scroll in line 40)
>
> Also, via preferences, allows to enable syncing of scroll, bookmarks, marks and folds between cloned views, live.
>
> Syncing features are disabled by default. You need to enable these via the preferences. Main menu -> Preferences -> Package Settings -> BufferScroll -> Settings Default. You may want to copy and paste your edited preferences to "Settings Users" located under the same sub-menu. To keep your preferences between updates.
>
> **Requested by Kensai this package now provides "typewriter scrolling": The line you work with is automatically the vertical center of the screen.**

https://github.com/titoBouzout/BufferScroll